# The usage of "an"

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

> Gehen Sie bitte zu Ihrem Kollegen, Herrn Marx, an die Kasse. Er erklärt Ihnen, wie die Kasse funktioniert.

Shouldn't the usage of "an" in the sentence above be as follows?

> Gehen Sie bitte zu Ihrem Kollegen, Herrn Marx, an der Kasse. Er erklärt Ihnen, wie die Kasse funktioniert.

If not, why isn't the dative form of "die Kasse" not used after "an"?

Answer (score 2):

These are both valid sentences, but mean slightly different things.

In the first sentence, "an die Kasse" describes the place that the person being addressed should walk to. It is in accusative because "walking to somewhere" is a direction.

In the second sentence, "an der Kasse" describes the place where Herr Marx is. It is in dative because Herr Marx is just there, he is not changing his location, there is no change of state.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

> Er geht *an die Kasse.*

That means he walks, and *an die Kasse* is a direction. So he walks towards the cashier.

> Er geht *an der Kasse.*

That means he walks, and *an der Kasse* is a location. So he is at the cashier and walks in circles at that place.

---

You always have to tell apart location and direction in German. With the nine prepositions *an, auf, hinter, in, neben, über, unter, vor* and *zwischen*, that distinction is made by the case. With accusative, those nine describe a direction, with dative, those nine describe a location.

But be careful: For example the prepostions *nach* and *zu* always take dative, but they always mean a direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, "to your colleague to the cashier" is meant. "to your colleague at the cashier" is not meant. Is "Gehen Sie bitte zu Ihrem Kollegen, Herrn Marx, der an der Kasse ist. Er erklärt Ihnen, wie die Kasse funktioniert." to be used for meaning "to your colleague at the cashier"?

Comment: In your example sentence you can actually use both. *Gehen Sie bitte zu Ihrem Kollegen an der Kasse.* treats *an der Kasse* as the location where your colleague is. While *Gehen Sie bitte zu Ihrem Kollegen an die Kasse.* treats *an die Kasse* as an adverbial that is on the same level as *zu Ihrem Kollegen*.

Comment: But that *Herrn Marx* breaks the continuity of the expression *zu Ihrem Kollegen an der Kasse*, which makes the latter phrasing sound better.

Comment: Does "Herrn Marx" not break the continuity of the expression "zu Ihrem Kollegen an die Kasse" since "zu Ihrem Kollegen" and "an die Kasse" are at the same level denoting direction?

Comment: It does, but in that phrasing the second adverbial isn't part of the first any more but independent.